# Typewriter effect working in codepen but not in jsfiddle / wordpress

Tags: javascript

Here's the JavaScript code I'm using in this pen -
 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZRbeg:

```
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
          new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
  };
```

It's vanilla js, maybe something with codepen putting the js into global scope and jsfiddle doesn't? Do I have to wrap it into some function? Just starting out with js, any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that nothing was added to the pen, an external script perhaps?

Comment: If your `jsFiddle` is set to run on `window.onload`, then your `window.onload` handler won't fire because the event has already taken place.

Comment: ...[here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ho6egpjq/) that changes the setting to run the code in the `head` with no wrapping instead of running it at `window.onload`. Works perfectly.